# How to modify an htaccess rule to include another paramater

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need an advice on how to modify the below `htaccess` rule.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search-results\.php\?vtype=(apple|orange)&vcategory=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search-results/%1/%2? [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search-results/(apple|orange)/([^/]*)/$ /search-results.php?vtype=$1&vcategory=$2 [L]
```

The rule currently makes some urls to look better. For example instead of this:

`www.website.com/search-results.php?vtype=apple&vcategory=fruit` I have this one:
`www.website.com/search-results/apple/fruit/`

What I need to do is to have the same rule work with another parameter like `search-results1`. So this url:

`www.website.com/search-results.php?vtype=apple&vcategory=fruit`
will look like this:
`www.website.com/search-results1/apple/fruit/`

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search-results\.php\?vtype=(apple|orange)&vcategory=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /(search-results|search-results1)/%1/%2? [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(search-results|search-results1)/(apple|orange)/([^/]*)/$ /search-results.php?vtype=$1&vcategory=$2 [L]
```

Any idea why the above does not work and what modification I should do?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no reason why the _internal rewrite_ (2nd rule) shouldn't work. However, the _redirect_ is not valid. You can't redirect to A _or_ B - you need to decide which one it should be. But that redirect is just to "catch" invalid URLs, it should still "work".